# WebSphere Process Server, DB2 SQLCODE=-1655, SQLSTATE=58030, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.57.82

Tags: process, db2, websphere

I have the ERROR:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: Error for batch element #3: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1655, SQLSTATE=58030, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.57.82.

Don't can start application process,

pass to restart data base and servers and problem persist

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your DB2.

Get your DBA to help you resolve the database issue(s).

WPS uses a number of databases as its configuration repository. If WPS cannot connect to these databases, it will not be able to start as you have observed in your case.

Look at what 1655 SQL Code represents:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fmsql01655c.html

SQL1655C
The operation could not be completed due to an error accessing data on disk.

Explanation
The failure to complete the operation is due to a problem in accessing data on a disk. The SQL statement has been rolled back or the operation has been aborted. The database remains accessible.

HTH

Manglu